# Definition of a meromorphic function by Forster's Lectures on Riemann Surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Here's the definition.

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface and $Y$ be an open subset of $X$.
A meromorphic function on $Y$ is a holomorphic function $f\colon Y' \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfying the following conditions, where $Y'\subset Y$ is a open subset.

(1) Every point $p\in Y - Y'$ is an isolated point.

(2) For every point $p\in Y - Y'$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow p} |f(x)| = \infty$.

The points of $Y - Y'$ are called the poles of $f$.

Then he stated in a remark:

Let $(U, z)$ be a coordinate neighborhood of a pole $p$ of $f$ with $z(p) = 0$.
Then $f$ can be expanded in a Laurent series $f = \sum_{n = -k}^{\infty} c_n z^n$ in a neighborhood of $p$.

Why is this so?  In other words, why $p$ cannot be an [essential singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity)?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about the order in which Forster makes definitions, but he seems to have *defined* poles in the above. Most people would then go on to define an essential singularity to be one that is neither removable nor a pole. So it seems by definition to me that it can't be an essential singularity because it is a pole.

Comment: An essential singularity wouldn't satisfy $(2)$, because in the case of an essential singularity, the limit will not be well defined (by the Picard theorem).

Comment: @BenA. Could we avoid using the Picard theorem?

Comment: @Makoto. I'm still thinking about how to avoid it. But you see, that $(2)$ is the sticking point, right?

Comment: @Makoto: You can get away with something a lot weaker and more elementary than Picard (e.g., the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem will suffice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the commentaries, assumption $(2)$ ensures that the singularity is a pole.

The statement is local, so let's say $f$ is a holomorphic function on $U\setminus{0}$, where $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ is a neighborhood of the origin in the complex plane, and that $\lim_{z\to 0}{|f(z)|} = \infty$. This allows us to assume, that $f$ doesn't vanish on $U\setminus{0}$ (by possibly shrinking $U$). Thus $g = 1/f$ is holomorphic on $U\setminus{0}$ and bounded near zero. Therefore is has a unique holomorphic extension to $U$, obviously given by $g(0) = 0$ and this zero point is isolated, hence it has a finite order of vanishing. But this order of vanishing is, by definition, the order of the pole of $1/g = f$, i.e. $f$ has a pole of finite order in $0$ (and especially not an essential singularity).